# Is there a guide to do a batch silent installation of Apache Tomcat 7.0.34 similar to a silent installation of SQL server 2008 R2 Express?

Tags: apache, tomcat, batch-file, installation, silent

I try to search and a lot of the links are not giving me the answer I am looking for.  SQL silent install was convenient with their config.ini file.  Is there something similar to do that with Apache Tomcat 7.0.34?

Answer (score 1):

All i have found for now is an example:

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.35.exe /S /D=INSTALLDIR
```

Note that both parameters `/S` and `/D` are **uppercase**.
In most windows installer thingy things you can use `/?` to dosplay help, like `-h` or `--help` in linux